# Query to retrieve only columns which have last name starting with 'K'

Tags: sql

[image: Here is an example of how the table looks]]

The name column has both first and last name in one column.

Look at the 'rep' column. How do I filter only those rep names where the last name is starting with 'K'?

Comment: To simple sample data. You could add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies to your example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the name is `<firstname> <lastname>` you can use:

```
where rep like '% K%'
```

Answer (score 2):

The way that table is defined won't allow you to do that query reliably--particularly if you have international names in the table.  Not all names come with the **given name** first and the **family name** second.  In Asia, for example, it is quite common to write names in the opposite order.

That said, assuming you have all western names, it is possible to get the information you need--but your indexes won't be able to help you.  It will be slower than if your data had been broken out properly.

```sql
SELECT rep,
  RTRIM(LEFT(LTRIM(RIGHT(rep, LEN(rep) - CHARINDEX(' ', rep))), CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RIGHT(rep, LEN(rep) - CHARINDEX(' ', rep)))) - 1)) as family_name
WHERE family_name LIKE 'K%'
```

So what's going on in that query is some string manipulation.  The dialect up there is SQL Server, so you'll have to refer to your vendor's string manipulation function.  This picks the second word, and assumes the family name is the second word.

- LEFT(str, num) takes the number of characters calculated from the left of the string
- RIGHT(str, num) takes the number of characters calculated from the right of the string
- CHARINDEX(char, str) finds the first index of a character

So you are getting the RIGHT side of the string where the count is the length of the string minus the first instance of a space character.  Then we are getting the LEFT side of the remaining string the same way.  Essentially if you had a name with 3 parts, this will always pick the second one.

You could probably do this with SUBSTRING(str, start, end), but you do need to calculate where that is precisely, using only the string itself.

Hopefully you can see where there are all kinds of edge cases where this could fail:

- There are a couple records with a middle name
- The family name is recorded first
- Some records have a title (Mr., Lord, Dr.)

It would be better if you could separate the name into different columns and then the query would be trivial--and you have the benefit of your indexes as well.

Your other option is to create a stored procedure, and do the calculations a bit more precisely and in a way that is easier to read.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Problem is with DB functions, you can't expect every vendor to do it the same way, or to have all the functions that another DB vendor has.  That's why I chose to give an answer to show it is _technically_ possible, and what DB the solution worked for.  As well as describing what that ugly SQL was doing.

Comment: Note, I also called out the reasons why they would want to separate the columns for the name in the database.